# How to add homestead box on vagrant using windows 7?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Im trying to add the laravel/homestead box on vagrant on windows 7. But I just can't. It says that the box could not be found and does not display any error message. I've researched it, but all the cases that I found had some kind of error message. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's tough debugging this on Windows, [Have you given this a try](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6764)?

Comment: It works! I don't like to use it on windows either, but I really need atm. Thank you so much. Post this as answer if you want to and I'll accept.